# In wheels that roll without friction, why don't we include the centripetal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Suppose we have a wheel rolling on a surface that has friction coefficient $\mu$ and it has velocity $v$,radius $r$, and mass $m$. When I calculate the Normal force for this wheel in order to calculate the frictional force $\mu N$, I often see only $mg$ included. Why isn't the $m \frac{v^2}{r}$ component included as well?

Take, for example, 5:24 in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvdmaZR6m8Q&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare. Here, the professor calculates the normal force as $mg$. Shouldn't it be $mg - m\frac{v^2}{r}$

Comment: When you say it has a velocity $v$ do you mean it is the constant linear velocity of the center of mass (COM)?

Comment: yeah or at the instant in time its velocity is $v$ and the friction is causing it to slow down.

Comment: I would like someone to confirm but it's probably because centripetal force incase of rolling is an internal force due to molecular bonds and has no role other than changing direction(no effect on velocity etc.). In case of revolution(circular motion) however it is generally provided by an external force

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Rolling wheel]

The diagram shows your wheel rolling to the right so it is rotating clockwise at some angular frequency $\omega$.

If you consider the force on some small part of the wheel shown by the red circle then that part is being accelerated upwards at $a = r\omega^2$. So there is indeed an upwards force on it of $F = mr\omega^2$, where $m$ is the mass of just the small part shown by the red circle.

But since the wheel is symmetric there is a matching part on the opposite side of the axle, shown by the green circle, where the force is equal and opposite. That means if we consider both parts the total force is zero.

And we can do this for every part of the wheel i.e. for every part of the wheel there is another part diametrically opposite that balances out the force. This means the net force on the wheel due to the rotation is zero, and the total force is indeed just $Mg$, where $M$ is the mass of the whole wheel.

Comment: I think the main role here is of internal forces. Internal forces are acting tangentially to not only red or green part but to all parts of ring and the net result of two tangential forces acting on each part  is towards center which plays role of centripetal force. And result of All internal forces is zero so need of any extra external force for internal forces.  correct me if I am wrong ?